# R Programing: Replacing values in multiple columns

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am very new to R Programming and working on an assignment to clean data. I uploaded csv file that has data with multiple columns.

The characteristic of data is basically yes/no but it coded as '1', '2', '3', '4'. Actually '2', '3', '4' do not have any meaning as the value only suggest whether its yes or no (if there is value >0 is yes, no value is no)

Here are example for summary of the data in a column

```
summary(data$P_FandB)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      1       1       1       1       1       1      54 
summary(data$P_ITMobile)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      2       2       2       2       2       2     362 
summary(data$P_Electronic)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      3       3       3       3       3       3     420 
summary(data$P_Furniture)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      4       4       4       4       4       4     432
```

I would like to replace, the value 2, 3, 4 of these selective columns in the dataset with 1 and 0 for NA. Please note that there are other columns that code 1, 2, 3, 4  but that's the code with meaning in the dataset.

This is what I do in R Programing for replacing 2, 3, 4 value to be 1;

```
data$P_FandB[which(data$P_FandB>1)]=1
data$P_ITMobile[which(data$P_ITMobile>1)]=1
data$P_Electronic[which(data$P_Electronic>1)]=1
data$P_Furniture[which(data$P_Furniture>1)]=1
```

I do have like 100 variables to convert into 1 and NA.

Can you please help suggest me the best way to clean these data?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use `lapply` with `replace` or `ifelse` i.e.  `data[selcols] <- lapply(data[selcols], function(x) replace(x, x>1, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the selected columns and replace the values to 1 and 0 for non-NA and NA respectively

```
selCols <- c("P_FandB", "P_ITMobile", "P_Electronic", "P_Furniture")
```

Or use the index of columns and then assign the output back to the columns of interest.

```
data[selCols] <- lapply(data[selCols], function(x) as.integer(!is.na(NA)))
```

Or without any looping, convert the dataset with the selected columns to a logical matrix, coerce it to binary (`+`), and assign it back to the selected columns.

```
data[selCols] <- +(!is.na(data[selCols]))
```

---

Or a faster option would be `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of data.table (`.SD`), replace the values as in the first solution, and assign (`:=`) it back to the columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, (selCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
               as.integer(!is.na(NA))), .SDcols = selCols]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could loop over the variables with `lapply()` and use a nested `ifelse()` to convert `NA` to `0` and values `> 1` to `1`.

Either create a vector of the names of your variables (look at `selCols` in @akrun's answer) or just use their column position in the dataset.

```
data[2:101] <- lapply(data[2:101], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, ifelse(x > 1, 1, 1)))
```

Small example:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1, NA, 3, 4))

  x  y
1 1  1
2 2 NA
3 3  3
4 4  4

data[1:2] <- lapply(data[1:2], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, ifelse(x > 1, 1, 1)))

  x y
1 1 1
2 1 0
3 1 1
4 1 1
```